# How to select uniformly random and unique elements from a list in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have this question a while back. Just wonder what is the best way (efficiency and elegance) to do this. The way I can think of is to use `RandomPermutation` to randomize the indices of the list, then choose the first `m` (of course needs to be less than the length of the list) elements from the list. But this requires the `Combinatorica` package.

Any better options?

Thank you.

Comment: The obvious algorithm is to remove elements as you select them. Very easily implemented recursively, but I haven't had access to mathematica in such a long time that I hesitate to try to implement it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh. It turns out (since version 6) that Mathematica will just do it for you: [`RandomSample[list, m]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomSample.html)

Answer (score 4):

As stated by Jefromi, for MMA6 and up `RandomSample` will do. For versions lower than 6 you can use the `RandomPermutation` function from the Combinatorica package (which is quite different from the MMA8 function `RandomPermutation`):

```
list[[ Take[RandomPermutation[Length[list]],m] ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, pointless as it's built in, but here is how to implement what Jefromi suggested:

```
ClearAll@getel;
getel[{els_, lst_}] := Module[
{pos = RandomInteger[{1, Length@lst}]},
{els~Join~{lst\[LeftDoubleBracket]pos\[RightDoubleBracket]}, 
  Delete[lst, pos]}]

ClearAll@getN;
getN[lst_, n_] := First@Nest[getel, {{}, lst}, n]
```

and usage: `getN[Range[10000], 3000]`. A mere 4 orders of magnitude slower than the built-in function...

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
s={{{3, 1}}, {{3, 2}}, {{4, 2}}, {{5, 1}}, {{5, 2}}}

i = 1;
j = 1;
rand[list_] := Drop[
list,
Flatten[
Position[list,   var[i++] = {Flatten[RandomSample[list, 1]]}     ]]
]

Table[var[j++], {Length[s]}]
```

This produces a random arrangement of `s` with no repeats:

```
{{{5, 2}}, {{3, 1}}, {{5, 1}}, {{4, 2}}, {{3, 2}}}
```

Comment: Or you could just use `RandomSample @ s` ;-)

Comment: Yes, I agree. RandomSample[l, m] is a better solution.